# What are these hoax ads/news on Facebook?

Tags: facebook

On a regular basis some hoax ads or misleaded articles can be seen on Facebook stream. There is a image from the real source of the ad but the link is pointing somewhere else. 
In short: Ad preview is taken from legal/real website but the user is forwarded different webaddress and redirecting back to the orginal website.

What are these redirects and how those are able to even create because you can't add two urls in the one ad?

Comment: "link is pointing somewhere else ... and redirecting back to the orginal website" - so the user does end up on the "original" website by clicking the link? If it is a regular redirect (which it could be for tracking) then the image could/would be pulled from the target. In which case they would only need to submit the source of the redirect? (But I'm guessing.) _Aside:_ FB have been trying to clamp down on "fake news" links, as it's a big problem. Unfortunately many users reportedly share these links before they've even read the article(!?), thus compounding the problem!

Comment: I'm closing this question as off-topic because it is not about your own website but instead about how Facebook works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called cloaking, where the spammer shows one URL to Facebook advertising team and another to the real user. Generally, those spammers use third party service for cloaking which may charges more then we believe, also it is invite based so Facebook/Google ads team don't know how they really do. They use many secret things to do cloaking but here is few of list that I know so far.

1. When the referral are from `dev.facebook.com` or `ads.facebook.com` or similar directory (On which FB ads team review ad) they show different URL.
2. They know IP address of facebook advertising team from which they will review ad.
3. They check GEO IP from which the ad will be reviewed, for example facebook advertising team review specific ad from particular geo/city, but if they review same URL from other geo then they will get different landing page or destination webpage.

***The solution is, simply report these kind of ads, and they will shut it down, in short time***.

Comment: "It's called cloacking" - Do you mean "cloaking"?

Comment: Yeah w3dk, Let me edit it.